# Ajax in MVC Page is not consuming a method in Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am very new to MVC .net core. I am implementing an ajax call in my Page to a Datatable but somehow it is not invoking my method in a controller. I do not get any error in my console. My code is below:

**startup => Configuration**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }
```

**startup => Configure**

```
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - AMS Customers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" />
</head>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

**CustomerController**

```
[Route("api/Customer")]
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

        public CustomerController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            return Json(new { data = await context.Customers.ToListAsync() });
        }
    }
```

**index.cshtml => For customer List**

```
<div class="col-12 border p-3">
    <table id="dt_load" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Plate Number</th>
                <th>Time Stamp</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/customer.js"></script>
}
```

**customer.js**

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});

function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#dt_customers').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/api/customer",
            "type": "GET",
            "dataType": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "firstName"},
            { "data": "middleName"},
            { "data": "lastName"},
            { "data": "plateNumber"},
            { "data": "timeStamp" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="text-center">
                        <a href="Customers/upsert?id=${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer; width:70px;">
                            Edit
                        </a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a class="btn btn-danger text-white" style="cursor:pointer; width:70px;">
                            Delete
                        </a>
                    </div>`;
                }, "width": "40%"
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "No data found"
        },
        "width": "100%"
    });
}
```

This is in my network tab on page load of Customer

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try changing `"url": "/api/customers",` to `"url": "/api/customer",`

Comment: @Shoejep, I did that. I still can't get it to work. Please see my Edit.

Comment: I created a very basic ASP.NET Core project and the action was getting called at `/api/customer`. You could inspect your browser network tab to see if any requests are being made to your action.

Comment: @Shoejep, please see my attachment. Thank you.

Comment: I have a feeling your `$(document).ready` isn't being called because the page has already loaded. Can you verify? Would also explain why your action isn't called and there's no errors.

Comment: It is Sir. I placed a console.log('CALLED'); . I see it in my console on load.

Comment: Shouldn't `<table id="dt_load"` be `<table id="dt_customers"`?

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes it should be "dt_customers" but the thing is why isn't my  controller called?

Comment: I should give you like a thousand points for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your DataTable element in `customer.js` should match up with your `Index.cshtml` element.

i.e. you should change `<table id="dt_load"` to be `<table id="dt_customers"`

Then on your server side, because your route is `[Route("api/Customer")]`, therefore in `customer.js`, your ajax url should be `"url": "/api/customer",` instead of `"url": "/api/customers",`